# JavaScript: How To Get Global Access To Array Values Created In A then{}

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to learn JavaScript and I think I'm running into a problem with scope. I'm trying to access an array created in a `then{}`, but I receive this error (`testJS.js:43 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined`) when I try to console.log the array value outside of the `then{}` where it was created.

In the code below, I can console.log the value of an indexed array (`**** works perfectly here ****`) when I'm inside of the `then{}`, but I can't get it to work outside of the `then{}` where I created it. See `**** does NOT work here ****`.

Also, I can see the data when I consol.log the entire array `**** I can see the data in the array though. ****`, but I can't access specific values. Screenshot below.

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**My Code**

```
var songsList = [];
    //Fetch JSON from URL -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch
    fetch('data.json')
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function(myJson) {
            var songData = (JSON.stringify(myJson));
            var obj = JSON.parse(songData);

            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript 
                for (index = 0; index < obj.length; ++index) {
                    var newSong = [];

                    var songUid = obj[index]['uid'];
                    var songName = obj[index]['songName'];
                    var songGenere = obj[index]['genere'];
                    var songUrl = obj[index]['url'];
                    var songID = songUrl.split("be/");
                            songID = songID[1];
                    var songListen = obj[index]['listen'];
                    var email = obj[index]['email'];

                        newSong.push(songUid);
                        newSong.push(songName);
                        newSong.push(songGenere);
                        newSong.push(songUrl);
                        newSong.push(songID);
                        newSong.push(songListen);
                        newSong.push(email);

                            songsList.push(newSong);

                }       //

            console.log('Song Title - '+songsList[0][1]); // **** works perfectly here ****

      });

    console.log('Song Title - '+songsList[0][1]); // **** does NOT work here ****

    console.log('Song Title - '+songsList); // **** I can see the data in the array though. ****
```

Comment: Why are you converting 3 times?
`.then(function(myJson) {
            var songData = (JSON.stringify(myJson));
            var obj = JSON.parse(songData);
` can be written `.then(function(obj) {`

Comment: What happen in the `fetch` is asynchronous. means when you console the array outside the `then` its still not fetched and the array is empty yet.

Comment: Also try this:
`.then(obj => { const songsList = obj.map(song => { 
  const listItem =  {uid, songName, genre, url, listen, email} = song; /* destruct the object */
  listItem.url = listItem.url.replace(/be\//,""); 
  return listItem;
})})` https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/pmazdwty/